A variation of the Riesz Lemma
Given a normed space $X$, a closed proper subspace $Y$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$, the Riesz Lemma states that there is $x\in X$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $d(x,Y)>\alpha$. Observe that also $d(-x,Y)=d(x,Y)>\alpha$. That is, the distance from the unit sphere of $\langle x \rangle$ (where $\langle A\rangle$ denotes the linear span of $A$) to $Y$ is at least $\alpha$.
I'm looking for a proof or counterexample for the following variation of the Riesz Lemma:
Given a normed space $X$, a closed proper subspace $Y$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$, there is $x\in X$ such that the distance from $\langle x\rangle$ to the unit sphere of $Y$ is at least $\alpha$.
I am mostly interested in positive answers, so partial positive answers would be nice if the result is false. Particularly, I'm only concerned with Banach spaces, so this can be assumed without problem.
EDIT: Pietro presented a clever construction in finite dimension and with $\mathrm{codim}(Y)=1$. Is there also a counterexample when $\dim(X)=\infty$ and $\mathrm{codim}(Y)=\infty$?

Notice that $|x|,$ coded as \|x\|, looks different from $||x||,$ and $|x||y|,$ coded as \|x\|\|y\|, looks very different from $||x|| ||y||,$ coded as ||x|| ||y||. The former notation is standard usage. $$ \begin{align} & ||x|| ||y|| \ {} \ & |x||y| \end{align} $$

@MichaelHardy, re, \lVert\rVert can work even better than \|\|.  Compare, for example, \|-x\| $|-x|$ to \lVert-x\rVert $\lVert-x\rVert$.  Although a bit awkward, this can be swept up in a macro like \newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}, and even repeated such macro definition can be semi-automated using \DeclarePairedDelimiter from mathtools.

Let's denote $B$ the unit ball of $X$. Geometrically, we are asking if there is a line $\langle x\rangle$ such that the ball $\alpha B$ can be translated along $\langle x\rangle$ and pass through the hole of $Y\setminus B $, that is we seek a non-zero $x$ such that $$ \big( \alpha B+ \langle x\rangle\big) \cap \big(Y\setminus B\big)=\emptyset.$$
I think the simplest counterexample is: $X:=\mathbb R^3$ with the box norm $\|(a,b,c)\|_\infty:=\max(|a|,|b|,|c|\}$ and $Y:=(1,1,1)^\perp=\{(a,b,c):a+b+c=0\}$. The section $Y\cap B$ is a regular hexagon with vertices in mid-points of some edges, but every projection of $\alpha B$ onto  $Y$ is a polygon with vertices in the projection of some vertices of $\alpha B$, thus never included in $Y\cap B$ for $\alpha$ too close to $1$. (Or just consider the angles between $Y$ and the faces of the cube).

Thanks for your answer, @PietroMajer. I'm just confused with a thing. The set $Y={(a,b,c) : a+b+c=1}$ isn't a linear subspace, right? It isn't closed by scalar multiplication.

That was a typo, sorry, fixed.

That is a clever construction, thank you @PietroMajer. As you said, the worst possible case is the closed hyperplanes. But, in the specific case where I am interested in applying that result, I have $Y$ with infinite codimension. Actually, I have $\dim(X)$ infinite and $\mathrm{codim}(Y)$=$\dim(X)$. Do you know a possible counterexample in that setting, where $\mathrm{codim}(Y)=\infty$? Should I post another question or just edit it with this add-on?

Maybe  a product of countably many copies of the above counterexample? So now $X$ is $\ell_\infty$ and $Y$ the subspace defined by $x_{3n}+x_{3n+1}+x_{3n+2}=0$ for all $n\ge0$.

Then if there were a non-zero $x\in \ell_\infty$ as required, some projection of it in  3-dimensional space $\text{span}(e_{3n},e_{3n+1},e_{3n+2})$ would be non-zero and would be ok for the 3D case.

(I've removed the initial sentence about the "worst case", that was ambiguous and not necessary)

I get it. This can even be made with an arbitrarily large number of copies. In that case, we have the space $l_\infty(M)$, where $M$ is a set with any cardinality. Thanks, @Pietro

Actually a norm for which your variation of Riesz Lemma is true for every closed subspace Y should be somehow special. I wonder what can be said about it.  Also, you can consider analogous properties more generally with d-dimensional subspaces Z  in place of the line $\langle x\rangle$...

A norm with the property for all closed proper $Y$ seems special indeed. Your counterexample is in a space with very good properties

Seems to me that if $Y$ has a dimension much smaller than $X$, there is $\langle x\rangle$ with the property, even for $\alpha=1$. The trick is to take the intersection of the Birkhoff-James orthogonal hyperplanes to each $y\in Y$. I think this is possible (that is, the intersection of the hyperplanes is larger than ${0}$) when $2^{|Y|}<|\dim(X)|$. However, that approach seems far from the most efficient (probably there is a better upper bound for the intersection of the hyperplanes being non-trivial and we are using $\alpha=1$. The $\epsilon$-Birkhoff James is way less restrictive).
